# How does Westboro Baptist Church support the idea that soldiers will go to hell?

Tags: biblical-basis

[Westboro Baptist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westboro_Baptist_Church) is a hyper calvinistic church with many inflammatory teachings, such as the idea that soldiers will go to hell. They have picketed at military funerals before. How do they support this teaching in the Bible?

Comment: I am deeply disturbed by W.B.C, who do not represent the Baptist denomination and who, with their wildly divergent, fringe position on many things, should populate a denomination of their own, IMHO.  I wonder if there are any W.B.C. members on this Stack who can attempt to provide an answer.

Comment: @MikeBorden I mean you don't have to be a WBC member to answer the question but it would be very interesting. I wonder if the members would not want to associate with the site due to its "neutral" nature that allows for all kinds of people on the site.

Comment: @LukeHill It's my honor for serving and thank you. I did a little research and found the following article. Hope this helps.  https://www.splcenter.org/fighting-hate/extremist-files/group/westboro-baptist-church  These are "spiritually" sick people that "obviously" do not know God.

Comment: The WBC are a couple of dozen people, and do not deserve the attention they get.

Comment: @curiousdannii that’s not a reason to downvote my question…

Comment: @LukeHill Votes are anonymous, and accusing people of downvoting your posts is rude. Please don't do it, you don't know who downvoted your question.

Comment: @curiousdannii I apologize if I came off as rude, but your comment appeared at the same time as it was downvoted. I just don’t understand why people keep downvoting questions that don’t fall within the grounds of downvoting without explanation. Maybe I need to make a meta post on this.

Comment: @LukeHill Downvote explanations are never required, because they always carry with them the meaning of "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". And I really don't know why you're complaining when I did leave a comment. The WBC are notorious, but have no right to be. The media should ignore them, and so should we. They're trolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm skeptical of the claim that they believe soldiers go to hell. At least, it needs a bit of nuance. They seem to believe *American* soldiers go to hell, but probably not soldiers generally.

I spent a bit of time searching their website and found an FAQ talking about why they have events at soldiers' funerals. Here's what it says:

> ### Why do you preach at... soldiers' funerals?
>
> To warn the people who are still living that unless they repent, they
> will likewise perish. When people go to funerals, it is one of the few
> times that they have sincere, sober thoughts of mortality, heaven,
> hell, eternity, etc., on their minds. It's the perfect time to warn
> them of things to come. It is a great kindness to remind people of the
> truth contained within God’s word of these sober, grave topics – the
> most important for any person to think of in their brief lives – while
> their minds are on such topics for that brief moment of sobriety...
>
> As for funerals of fallen soldiers – when a nation rises up in pride
> against God, one of the ways that God punishes that nation is by
> killing her men of war. “She hath been proud against the LORD, against
> the Holy One of Israel. Therefore shall her young men fall in the
> streets, and all her men of war shall be cut off in that day, saith
> the LORD.” (Jeremiah 50:29-30). Soldiers’ funerals often become more
> of a ‘patriotic pep rally’ than they do anything else. Rather than
> ‘mourning’ the death of someone who willingly fought for a nation
> awash in sin at every level, those present at such occasions should
> rather mourn, deeply and with great shame, for their sins – as the
> same God who took the breath of life of those fallen will shortly take
> ours. What state of heart will you have when the Lord comes to take
> your breath of life? What of eternity and your never-dying soul? “What
> will ye do in the day of visitation?” (Isaiah 10:3).

So it looks like they have some bad exegesis and misunderstandings about what Jesus said regarding the dead burying their dead, but none of this indicates that they think all soldiers go to hell by virtue of being soldiers. Rather, they seem to think America is cursed for rising up against God like so many of the Old Testament cities and nations and that her soldiers are being struck down because of this.

If that were true, I would expect far more American casualties in the 20 years we've been at war since 9/11. Even counting suicides, which far outnumber KIA deaths, [US soldiers only died at a rate of roughly 5 per day over the course of roughly 20 years](https://watson.brown.edu/costsofwar/costs/human/military/killed). It's about 1 per day if we only count those KIA. That's not to downplay the loss of life, but 1 soldier dead per day is hardly a divine reckoning. God can kill a lot more soldiers than that.

I also found a video they produced called *Thank God for Dead Soldiers*. The introduction to this indicates to me that they are taking the erroneous view that God actively wills every event, good or evil, rather than distinguishing between the active and passive wills of God, as most orthodox Christian theologians would do. The narrator of this 2 minute video states that these soldiers who are going to fight in the middle east are seeking a "macho rush" and don't realize "that God is their enemy." I'm not certain if this is meant to imply she thinks God is on the side of Muslims - an odd view for fundamentalist Christians to take - or that He is punishing these soldiers for their prideful belief that they can just "go over there and push buttons and win."

After reviewing their own material, I don't think that they believe soldiers generally go to hell, but that soldiers willingly fighting in an unjust war for a corrupt nation that has made itself the enemy of God go to hell, and that they further believe that all American soldiers are culpable of willful participation in injustice via war.

The attitudes the woman describes the soldiers as having are major sins of pride (think they can "just go over there... and win"), greed (they are fighting for a paycheck and a nice benefits package (this is laughable)), and bloodlust (they are seeking a "macho rush"). Certainly these are damnable sins, and that is easily supported by scripture, and those who die without repenting of them probably go to hell. It seems they are making a hasty sweeping judgement of all American soldiers as being unrepentantly guilty of these sins, thus damned to hell.